# select-string not taking variable in powershell

Tags: powershell, syntax, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have stored a MAC address as a string in a variable:

```
$macaddress= "1234567"
```

I'm trying to store the output from a command in another variable:

```
 $testing = { arp -a; | select-string  $macaddress }
 Write-Host $testing
```

If the command is executed in PowerShell, I do not see the value of `$macaddress`. It displays as a '$macaddress' in the screen instead of its value "1234567".

Please help me set the value of `$macaddress` correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is *not* how you define variable `$macaddress`, but in *how you try to capture command output*.
Remove the enclosing `{ ... }` and the `;`:

```
$testing = arp -a | select-string $macaddress
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

`{ ... }` creates a *script block*, which is a piece of source code (loosely speaking) for *later* execution (e.g., with operators `.` or `&`).

If you pass a script block to `Write-Host` - [whose use you should generally avoid](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), by the way - it is converted to a *string*, and the string representation is the *literal contents* of the script block between `{` and `}` - that's why you saw `$macaddress` appear (unexpanded) in your output.

`;` terminates a command, and it is only necessary if you place *multiple* commands on a single line.
A pipeline is still considered a *single* command, even though it is composed of multiple sub-commands; do *not* attempt to use `;` in a pipeline - you'll break it (and, in fact, even your script-block-creating command would break).

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
$macAddress = "00-01-02-03-04"
arp -a | Select-String $macAddress
```

If you want to extract the IP address related to the MAC address, you can do this:

```
$macAddress = "00-01-02-03-04"
arp -a | Select-String ('\W*((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}(?:[0-9]{1,3}))\W+(' +
  $macAddress + ')') | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: What are the outer brackets of select-string for? You did `select-string ('('+$var+'regex'))`